# EXIBIR DADOS DE DOIS FORMS EM UM TEMPLATE DJANGO

Tags: django, django-templates

Quero exibir os dados de dois forms em um template. Preciso que liste somente a field=nome.

views.py

```
def lista_cadastro(request):
    cli_pf = DadosPessoaFisica.objects.all().order_by('nome')
    cli_pj = DadosPessoaJuridica.objects.all().order_by('nome')

    clientes = {
        'cli_pf': cli_pf,
        'cli_pj': cli_pj
    }

    return render(request, 'cadastros/lista_cad.html', clientes)
```

forms_pf.py

```
class FormPessoaFisica(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DadosPessoaFisica
        fields = '__all__'
```

forms_pj.py

```
class FormPessoaJuridica(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DadosPessoaJuridica
        fields = '__all__'
```

lista_cad.html

```
<div>
     {% for cliente_pj in cli_pj%}
         {{cliente_pj.nome}}
     {% endfor %}

     {% for cliente_pf in cli_pf %}
         {{cliente_pf.nome}}
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

models.py

```
class DadosPessoa(models.Model):
    UF_CHOICES = (
        ('AC', 'Acre'),
        ('AL', 'Alagoas'),
        ('AP', 'Amapá'),
        ('BA', 'Bahia'),
        ('CE', 'Ceará'),
        ('DF', 'Distrito Federal'),
        ('ES', 'Espírito Santo'),
        ('GO', 'Goiás'),
        ('MA', 'Maranão'),
        ('MG', 'Minas Gerais'),
        ('MS', 'Mato Grosso do Sul'),
        ('MT', 'Mato Grosso'),
        ('PA', 'Pará'),
        ('PB', 'Paraíba'),
        ('PE', 'Pernanbuco'),
        ('PI', 'Piauí'),
        ('PR', 'Paraná'),
        ('RJ', 'Rio de Janeiro'),
        ('RN', 'Rio Grande do Norte'),
        ('RO', 'Rondônia'),
        ('RR', 'Roraima'),
        ('RS', 'Rio Grande do Sul'),
        ('SC', 'Santa Catarina'),
        ('SE', 'Sergipe'),
        ('SP', 'São Paulo'),
        ('TO', 'Tocantins')
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=UF_CHOICES)


class DadosPessoaFisica(DadosPessoa):
    SEXO_CHOICE = (
        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Feminino')
    )
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    rg = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    dt_nasc = models.DateField()
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEXO_CHOICE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nome}'


class DadosPessoaJuridica(DadosPessoa):
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    insc_estadual = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nome}'
```

Desse jeito que eu fiz primeiro mostra os dados dos forms_pj e depois os dados do forms_pf. Teria alguma forma de exibir esses dados de forma que fiquem ordenados?

Comment: O código esta no meu github caso alguem queira verificar https://github.com/petersonbg/estudo-django-peterson-batista/tree/master/cadastro-pf-pj

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizando o [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/).
Utilizando o values_list é o equivalente à fazer a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT nome from ...
```

Isso vai retornar um objeto do tipo queryset, que vai retornar uma lista de tuplas.

Se estiver fazendo o select de apenas uma coluna, pode utilizar a opção flat. Assim pode ter uma lista de valores singulares, ao invés de ter uma lista de tuplas de valores singulares.

A solução final ficaria:

```
cli_pf = list(DadosPessoaFisica.objects.values_list('nome', flat=True))
cli_pj = list(DadosPessoaJuridica.objects.values_list('nome', flat=True))
```

Agora possuímos duas listas distintas contendo apenas o atributo nome de cada coleção (que no banco de dados são tabelas).

Agora basta ordenar e apresentar o resultado no `views.py`

Você deve alterar o seu `views.py`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
def lista_cadastro(request):
    cli_pf = list(DadosPessoaFisica.objects.values_list('nome', flat=True))
    cli_pj = list(DadosPessoaJuridica.objects.values_list('nome', flat=True))

    todos_os_nomes = cli_pf + cli_pj
    todos_os_nomes.sort()
    clientes = {
        'tudo': todos_os_nomes,
    }
    return render(request, 'cadastros/lista_cad.html', clientes)
```

Depois em seu template basta alterar a variável que percorre a lista de nomes:

***lista_cad.html***

```
<div>
     {% for t in tudo%}
        {{t}}
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Consulte a documentação de [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Em minha solução eu removi a ordenação dos elementos via o order_by, porque após finalizar a query será necessário ordenar novamente todo o conjunto de dados, desta forma fiz o order_by apenas após concatenar todos os valores na mesma lista.